# Html5 validate input value not eqaul to by default value

Tags: html

I want to validate input value not equal to by default value through html5 validation,is it possible?

```
 <input type="text" name="First Name" value="First Name" id="FirstName"
 required=""  title="First Name is Required!" >
```

when user click on submit button, if input filed has value= First Name
then show error.

I don't want to use placeholder="First Name".

Is there a way to validate using pattern attribute, 
like pattern="!First Name"   <-Stupid logic :)

Comment: Why don't you use `placeholder="First Name"` instead of `value="First Name"`

Comment: I need to use value="First Name" not placeholder

Comment: Why do you need to use that? What happens if the browser has javascript disabled - the value "First Name" will be sent to the server. Using the `placeholder` attribute will solve the same problem ... just remember that it is not meant to be used as a replacement of the `label` - doing such is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript for this try below:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="First Name" value="First Name" id="FirstName" required="" title="First Name is Required!">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="if (document.getElementById('FirstName').value == 'First Name') return false;">
</form>
```

Comment: I have more than one input fields in form . :)

Comment: Then you can create a js function which will validate all fields and call it on click

Answer (score 2):

Adding a pattern should work.

```
<input type="text" name="First Name" value="First Name" id="FirstName"
 required=""  title="First Name is Required!" pattern="^((?!First Name).)*$">
```

This will throw a error if your value contains the string "First Name".

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution: use the `placeholder` attribute instead of the `value` attribute ... but do not use it as a replacement for a label (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) page on `input`).

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First name is required" ... />
```

This means that you do not need to have any logic to check the default value has not been filled.

Comment: I know about placeholder, but it is necessary to use value attribute.

Comment: Have you heard of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys - I was just investigating if using the `value` attribute really was needed. e.g. one answer could be "because I am using a CMS that does not expose the attributes you mention"